# Document Library Filter by Metatag to 2nd, 3rd Level

Tags: document-library, managed-metadata, sharepoint-list-filter

First question from me here, so please go easy on me, if my question is stupid.

I'm building a document library in SharePoint for photos, videos and such. For the sake of this example, let's say it's photos of various foods - 'cause, who does not like to eat, eh?

In order to organize my images I've built some Managed Metadata Term Set in the Term Store describing what's on the pictures. Something like this:

- Fruits
- - Citrus Fruits
- - - Lemons
- - - Oranges
- - Berries
- - - Strawberries
- - - Blueberries

Next step, I made a column in my Document Library and tagged my photos up to the third level, e.g. with "Blueberries".

So far so good, but now I'm stuck. What I can't figure out, and I hope you can tell me how to do, is how can I now filter my images also by the 1st and 2nd level, e.g. by "Fruits" or "Berries"? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In my testing, I don't see getting third level items returned in the results, in this case *Berries:Strawberries*, when filter is on on a 2nd level item like *Berries*.

See my testing result below:

**Managed Metadata** in a list (ImgType is Managed Metadata column, and when created, "Display the entire path to the term in the field" option was selected.

[image]

**Click [Select All] to get to Tree View**

[image]

**Select Managed Metadata Terms from the Tree View to Apply Filter**
[image]

---

**You can read further on** [Use filtering to modify a SharePoint view](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-filtering-to-modify-a-sharepoint-view-3d8efc52-0808-4731-8f9b-3dfaeacea3d4?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)

**Also, on** [What is the list and library filters pane](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/what-is-the-list-and-library-filters-pane-293561ed-fb2e-4fb2-9a9f-8a21e299e323)

Comment: Thank you @Matiur Rahman! It's unfortunate that the 'tree branches' do not automatically get selected as well, but this helps a lot already! I just fear that going via the overall filter (rather than the column filter) might not be so intuitive for normal users. Do you know if there's a way to set a column to "Tree Type" permanently?